# a ; without statement in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I was looking at a code sample in C#. There is `;` without any statement before it. I thought it is typo. I tried to compile with `;`. It compiled fine. What is the use of `;` without any code statement?

I'm using VS 2010, C# and .Net 4.0

```
  private void CheckSmcOverride(PatLiverSmc smc)
  {
     ;
     if (smc.SmcOverride && smc.Smc != null 
              && smc.Smc.Value < LiverSmcConst.SMC_OVERRIDE_POINT)
     {
          smc.Smc = 10;
          _logger.DebugFormat("CheckSmcOverride: Override SMC {0}", smc.Smc);
     }
  }
```

Comment: Does it compile without the semicolon as well?

Comment: It is just an empty statement. It is valid and making it invalid would cost in resources for little benefit.

Comment: It means nothing. It's an empty statement. Try removing it and recompiling.

Comment: My code compiles just fine with semi colon with no statement too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A semicolon in C# is simply to denote an end-of-a-statement. Empty statements, or just a `;` by itself, are valid.

You could have the following on a line by itself inside any function in C# and it should will compile fine:

```
; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;
```

On the same topic, but semi-different from the question at hand, is an empty set of curly-brackets, `{ }`. These denote a "code block", but are valid just about anywhere in your code. Again, you could have something like the following on a single line and it will still compile fine:

```
{ } { ;;;;;;;;;; } { }
```

In the end, the empty-statement and empty-code blocks all compile down to "nothing to see here folks, move along" and can, *in most cases*, be removed from the code without consequence.

Comment: I've seen a question the other day (or a comment in C# chat, not sure which) in which the IL generated from an empty set of curly-brackets generated one single additional IL instruction. If I had a reference to where I saw it, I'd link it here...

Comment: @ShotgunNinja so are you saying that using if(something); versus if(something){}; saves one byte of IL? (I did check that ; didn't generate a IL NOP which it doesn't)

Answer (score 7):

As a c# developer I use the 'empty statement'

```
;
```

(a useful case as a comment requested)

when I have a multi line lambda and I want to examine the last line of evaluation i.e.

```
list.ForEach(x=>
              {
                x.result = x.Value * x.AnotherValue;
                ; // otherwise I can't ever see these as you can't break on the end brace of an anonymous function
              })
```

as a way to break point inside some code after evaluation of the line before i.e.

```
void SomeFunct()
{
    int a = someOtherFunct();
    ; //I want a breakpoint here but...
    //there is some huge code segment that will get skipped before I can breakpoint
}
```

Comment: Your use of it does not equal why it is allowed ;)

Comment: @ispiro nearly all of them, the question is what is its use with no code statement. it has more uses than just wanting a breakpoint, Servy provides an excellent and comprehensive description of even more uses just to name one

Comment: @RhysW added lambda breakpoint example (a regular use for empty statement break point for me)

Answer (score 6):

It's a statement that does nothing.  Normally this would be pointless and could just be removed, but there are times where a statement is expected and you really want nothing to happen.

Sometimes you see this with loops that cause side effects and so need no body:

```
int count = 0;
while(isTheRightNumber(count++))
    ;
```

Personally I dislike such code examples and discourage the practice as they tend to be harder to understand than loops that have side effect free conditions.  Using a set of empty braces is a bit clearer, as is including a relevant comment, such as:

```
int count = 0;
while(isTheRightNumber(count++)) 
    { } //empty by design
```

Another example is the pattern of using a `for` loop for an infinite loop:

```
for(;;)
{
    //stuff
}
```

is essentially the same as:

```
while(true)
{
    //stuff
}
```

Comment: On the topic of the For loop, im sure its the fact the paramaters are empty that make it infinite not the fact it has semi colons, as those are always there when you give parameters too. the  semicolons themselves dont make it infinite, the lack of parameters do

Comment: @RhysW The point is that `for()` wouldn't compile, you need to have 3 separate statements inside the declaration of the loop, but you don't need them to do anything; you effectively want 3 empty statements, hence the use of a statement that is just `;`.

Comment: perhaps a little bit of explanation would go nicely with that then? nothing wrong with providing the curious with more relevant information!

Comment: @RhysW The info is in the comments if anyone is interested; personally I don't use the pattern and find `while(true)` to be much more readable, it seems overly verbose to expand on it in the answer.

Comment: i meant more to denote that the reason it is infinite is because youre supplying three empty statements,

Answer (score 3):

It's an [empty statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). I never used it, but it exists in many languages.

Answer (score 2):

semicolon(;) indicated the end of a statement. so if you just add a semicolon without anything... it means it is empty statment

Answer (score 1):

An empty statement is sometimes used when a statement expects a block but you don't want it to do anything.

For example:

```
for(i=0; array[i]!=null; i++)
    ;
```

or for nested if then elses without braces:

```
// don't really do this kids
if(cond1)
  if(cond2)
    doit();
  else
    ;
else
  dont();
```

Sometimes used for 'if' clarity:

```
if(somecomplicatedconditionisnotfalseinverted()) // <-- this is already complicated enough, let's not ! that.
  ; // do nothing
else {
  ohnoes();
}
```

But in your example, it does absolutely nothing when built for release and just adds a nop when built for debug, so you can drop a breakpoint on it.

Comment: your dangling `else` case would be much more effectively solved with the use of braces.  I've never actually seen that solution before, but I know I wouldn't want to see it in production code.

Comment: As for your edit, the addition of a noop `if` and an additional `else` is more complex than a `!` in my opinion.  If the expression is overly complex it should probably be broken up into sub expressions that result in intermediate variables being stored before the `if`, or possibly a `bool` returning method (like the code you have there), if it's really that complex.